# Knockout.js v3.0.0 with IE8 and JQuery 1.9

Tags: knockout.js

Does KO v3.0.0 work with IE8 and JQuery 1.9
If it does, are there specific features that are not compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the [browser support](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/browser-support.html)-page of knockoutjs it should work.

if you have the setup you will be developing in, you can [run the tests](http://knockoutjs.com/spec/runner.html)